# NSInvalidArgumentException on NSPredicate call

Tags: swift, nspredicate

So I have the following code which gives me a NSInvalidArgumentException.

```
let test = "AND ANY typeId = 25"
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "latitude BETWEEN {%f,%f} AND longitude BETWEEN {%f,%f} %@", (latitude-0.10), (latitude+0.10), (longitude-0.10), (longitude+0.10), test)
```

However, if I remove the %@ and test element, the call goes through just fine. What am I missing here? afaik, test is a string and %@ is what I should use to reference a string object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html  says

> Important: Use a %@ format specifier only to represent an expression. Do not use it to represent an entire predicate.
>   If you attempt to use a format specifier to represent an entire predicate, the system raises an exception.

You could instead try

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "latitude BETWEEN {\(latitude-0.1),
\(latitude+0.1)} AND longitude BETWEEN {\(longitude-0.1),\(longitude+0.1)} 
\(test)")
```